# OpenCV cannot open stream using IP camera

Tags: c++, opencv, ip-camera

I have 2 identical IP cameras and I'm trying to access stream of them. To do this I'm using

> http://username:password@ip/axis-cgi/mjpg/video.cgi?m.mjpg

I give this to OpenCV VideoCapture. And now let's consider that there is camera_1 and camera_2. Cameras have different IPs, so there is no conflicts. The problem is that I can't open stream in OpenCV of camera_1, but in the browser it works. And with camera_2 is problem that sometimes I can open the stream in OpenCV and sometimes I can't do this (I don't change any settings, just run application ones and it works, after that I close application and run it again and it doesn't work).

So what can be the reason? Where to looking for a solution?

Comment: Do camera1 and camera2 have identical settings? Are they the same model?

Comment: Yes, camera_1 and camera_2 have identical settings and they the same model. They bought at the same time.